# Object in activity scope cannot be injected into ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

this is my activity module:

```
@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainModule::class])
abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity
```

Here's my ViewModel module:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)


@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMainViewModel(viewModel: MainViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

this is my MainModule:

```
@Module
class MainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSearcher(context: Context): Searcher {
        LogUtils.e("Provide Searcher")
        val searchFolder = File(context.filesDir, FOLDER_SEARCH_PARENT)
        return Searcher(searchFolder.absolutePath)
    }
}
// My MainViewModel's constructor:
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(val preferencesOnGlobalScope: MyPreferences, val searcher: Searcher)
```

This is how I get `MainViewModel` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
// get view model on onCreate
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[MainViewModel::class.java]
```

However, I always get this error: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] io.abcxyz.Searcher cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.` Hmm, what's that? I provided it on `MainModule`. Can you guys give me any advice, please?

P/s: without the `Searcher` param on Constructor, my viewmodel can be injected normally.

Comment: have you added `ViewModelModule` as a Sub modules in any module ? if yes then pls add code

Comment: @ADM yes, I did `@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainModule::class])`.

Comment: Remove `@Singleton` from your `ViewModelFactory` and it should probably work

Comment: @DavidMedenjak no, it did not. Perhaps, I get it wrong? `Searcher` should be destroyed when activity recreated, but the `ViewModel` are not.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find solution for this one?